# $\{E_k\}$ are measurable subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove that $\{\chi_{E_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy sequence in measure iff following holds

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $\{E_k\}$ are measurable subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove that $\{\chi_{E_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy sequence in measure if and only if $\lim_{k,j\rightarrow\infty}\mu((E_k\setminus E_j)\cup(E_j\setminus E_k))=0$.

$\{\chi_{E_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy in measure $\forall\epsilon,\delta>0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $k,j\geq N$ implies $\mu({|\chi_{E_k}-\chi_{E_j}|\geq\delta})<\epsilon$.

I noticed that $|\chi_{E_k}(x)-\chi_{E_m}(x)|=1$ if and only if $x\in((E_k\setminus E_j)\cup(E_j\setminus E_k))$. Can anyone help me how to go further than this?

Comment: I would start by writing down the definition of what it means for a sequence to be Cauchy in measure, and then using that definition for the sequence you have. Have you tried that? If you have, please edit your post to include what you’ve found. If you haven’t, please do and then edit your post with what you find.

Comment: A visual aid may help, note that

$$
(E_k\setminus E_j)\cup(E_j\setminus E_k)=E_k\,\triangle\, E_j
$$

where $\triangle $ is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Comment: Draw a picture for two arbitrary sets and use the previous comments-

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Thanks for your comments. I edited the post.